# Is there any way in Scala to have "ad-hoc" ADTs?

Tags: scala, algebraic-data-types

I want to completely get rid of exceptions in my Scala code, instead, return explicit / typed results (ADTs) from methods like this:

```
class SomeService {

  def method1: Method1Result = ...
}

object SomeService {

  trait Method1Result
  object Method1Result {
    case class Success(id: String) extends Method1Result
    case object AlreadyExists  extends Method1Result
    case object Error extends Method1Result
  }
}
```

But as you see, it's too boilerplate...

Ideally, I'd like to have something like this:

```
class SomeService {
  def method1: Success(id: String) | AlreadyExists | Error
}
```

So as you see, ADT is defined in the return type of the `method1`

May be there is some compiler plugins or annotation processing libraries
which allow to write such code and generate ADT's under the hood?

Or what's the best practice in Scala if I want to return typed results from the method?

Comment: **Scala 3** will have [`union types`](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/union-types.html). But for now, there is no other alternative.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Coproduct` from `shapeless`. Not sure if it makes sense to go this road in application-level code.

```
import shapeless.{:+:, CNil, Coproduct}

case class Success(id: String)
case class AlreadyExists
case class Error
type AllThree = Success :+: AlreadyExists :+: Error :+: CNil
```

Or you can create yourself types like 
`Either3[A, B, C]`, `Either4[A,B,C,D]`,... and solve it with some amount of boilerplate.

Answer (score 2):

Scala 3 might bring [union types](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/union-types.html) where we will be able to write exactly that. You can try it out in [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/?target=dotty) by selecting Dotty compiler target.

For example https://scastie.scala-lang.org/19tnxxxyTua2utD6QCocaw

```
object Main extends App {  
  case class Success(id: String)
  case object AlreadyExists
  case object Error

  def method1: Success | AlreadyExists.type | Error.type = AlreadyExists

  println(method1)
}
```

which outputs

```
AlreadyExists
```

Comment: For ADT there is enum syntax https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/enums/adts.html